# How to fix can not find dir in pathToPartitionInfo (selecting/counting from HIVE table on EMR)

Tags: amazon-ec2, hive

I've set up an interactive hive session and load apache weblog date into a table directly from an s3 bucket:

```
    DROP TABLE apachelog;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE apachelog (
  host STRING,
  identity STRING,
  user STRING,
  time STRING,
  request STRING,
  status STRING,
  size STRING,
  referer STRING,
  agent STRING)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = "([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) ([^ ]*) (-|\\[[^\\]]*\\]) ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") (-|[0-9]*) (-|[0-9]*)(?: ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\") ([^ \"]*|\"[^\"]*\"))?",
  "output.format.string" = "%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s %8$s %9$s"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3n://OperationOverkill/';
```

I can then sucessfully select from it like so:

```
SELECT * FROM apachelog LIMIT 5;
```

But counting (or anything requiering actual map-reduce does not:

```
SELECT COUNT(host) FROM apachelog;
```

The error message:

```
Job Submission failed with exception 'java.io.IOException(cannot find dir = s3n: //OperationOverkill/access_clickkiller_12-08-08.log in pathToPartitionInfo: s3n ://OperationOverkill/)'
```

I google and found a [similar question on AWS Support forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=372670#372670)  but I hope for quicker pointers/help from SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a Bug, It may work for S3 if you do not use bucket root, but I could not get to work for HDFS (Something like hdfs:///path/to/folder/):
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-7774

Since bug is fixed in Hive 0.14, you need to use version higher than that.

In context of AWS,

If you are following sample code from here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/calling-emr-with-java-sdk.html
You are probably using Hive 0.13.*:
See this:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingEMR_SupportedHiveVersions.html

You can instead follow this link, which shows new way of creating cluster with new AMI version:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-4.5.0/emr-release-differences.html#emr-release-label

For "release-lable" 4 or 5, you can get new Hive version, which should resolve the issue, see this for EMR(AMI) to hive version mapping:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com//ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-release-components.html

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, but using a subdirectory in s3 fixed it.  So, I would try putting your files in something like "s3n://OperationOverkill/subdir/" and using that.